# Python EEL module unable to use import bottle.ext.websocket as wbs ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle.ext.websocket'

Tags: python, websocket, pip, bottle, eel

I am trying to create a GUI in python using plain HTML, CSS, JS. I am using python eel module to create a GUI from it. When i tried to execute .py file it says module not found. Here are the code and error

**main.py**

```py
import eel

eel.init("./Evo/Body/Comp")

eel.start("desktop.html")
```

When I execute this code by using

```bash
python main.py
```

It gives this error

```bash
main.py", line 1, in <module>
import eel
\Lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
import bottle.ext.websocket as wbs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle.ext.websocket'
```

Earlier it was running well and fine but due to some issue i need to reset my PC. After reset when i re-installed everything then i am unable to run eel module and again and again same error occurs.

Answer (score 5):

### Problem

If you're using Python 3.12 release, it probably broke the `bottle.ext.websocket` import

According to the [maintainer](https://github.com/brentvollebregt)

> As described in [#433](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues/433), auto-py-to-exe fails to launch when run using Python 3.12 due to a bottle issue.

### Fix

auto-py-to-exe just released support for Python 3.12.

[Pull Request](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues/433)

[Release](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/releases/tag/v2.41.0)

Upgrade using:

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

### Workaround (Outdated)

Fortunately, `bottle-websocket` can be used and should work the same.
I got mine working using Python 3.12.
You just have to change an import in `__init__.py` in the eel module.

Find this import line:

```
import bottle.ext.websocket as wbs
```

and replace it with the one below:

```
import bottle_websocket as wbs
```

Make sure you have these up-to-date:

```
pip install --upgrade bottle-websocket setuptools
```

Save changes then run `auto-py-to-exe` again.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks buddy it works fine for but but haven't tested for pyInstaller coz i am developing it. But it was not even working directly without converting to exe. But now it works.

Comment: @JunaidParkar 
Hi, there's an official fix now. auto-py-to-exe provided a [quick fix](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/pull/434) for this issue. It should be resolved now. Just make sure to force reinstall when upgrading. `pip install auto-py-to-exe --upgrade --force-reinstall`

Comment: The outdated solution works for me, even though I can't run auto-py-to-exe

Answer (score 2):

To solve this error, install `bottle` using this command: `pip install git+https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle.git`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using auto-py-to-exe to package your app.

After inserting necessary details (script file,, extra files etc), you would see an advanced options tab probably below, click on it to expand it, look for the hidden imports label and insert "bottle-websocket" in the input field representing the hidden imports, that's all you need to do

Comment: But i am just executing python script for development. I am not converting to exe coz currently i am developing that app. But when i start the app using "python main.py" it says bottle.ext.websocket module not found